Issues in GCP Cloud Build when trying to build a signed APK
I am having an issue when trying to run a build using Cloud Build on GCP for my Android Application.
The error message:
"Step #2:   - In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication' property 'signingConfigData.signingConfigData.storeFile' specifies file '/root/.gradle/daemon/7.5/keystore.jks' which doesn't exist."
I have set in the release section of my App level build.gradle:
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.gradle/daemon/7.5/keystore.jks")
            storePassword System.getenv("GCLOUD_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("GCLOUD_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("GCLOUD_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            buildConfigField("String", "BUGSNAG_KEY", "\"${System.env.BUGSNAG_KEY}\"")

        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            buildConfigField("String", "BUGSNAG_KEY", "\"${System.env.BUGSNAG_KEY}\"")
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        }
    }

And this is my cloudbuild.yaml file:
steps: 
- name: 'gcr.io/ronin-pos/gradle-node-android:latest'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk
    export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider

    apt-get update
    apt-get install -y unzip curl openjdk-11-jdk  # Install unzip, curl, and JDK
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64  # Set JAVA_HOME
    export PATH=$$JAVA_HOME/bin:$$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin

    export REACT_APP_HASURA_GRAPHQL_SECRET=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="_REACT_APP_HASURA_GRAPHQL_SECRET")
    export BUGSNAG_KEY=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="_BUGSNAG_KEY")
    export DD_CLIENT_TOKEN=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="_DD_CLIENT_TOKEN")
    export DD_APPLICATION_ID=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="_DD_APPLICATION_ID")
    export HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="_HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET")
    export PRODUCTION_REACT_APP_HASURA_GRAPHQL_SECRET=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="_PRODUCTION_REACT_APP_HASURA_GRAPHQL_SECRET")
    export PRODUCTION_BUGSNAG_KEY=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="_PRODUCTION_BUGSNAG_KEY")
    
    # Ensure the .gradle/daemon/7.5 directory exists
    mkdir -p $$HOME/.gradle/daemon/7.5

    # Access secrets directly without substitutions
    export GCLOUD_KEYSTORE_CONTENT=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="GCLOUD_KEYSTORE_CONTENT")
    export GCLOUD_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="GCLOUD_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
    export GCLOUD_KEY_ALIAS=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="GCLOUD_KEY_ALIAS")
    export GCLOUD_KEY_PASSWORD=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="GCLOUD_KEY_PASSWORD")

    # Validate that the keystore file was created successfully
    if [ ! -f $$HOME/.gradle/daemon/7.5/keystore.jks ]; then
      echo "Error: Keystore file could not be created."
      ls -l $$HOME/.gradle/daemon/7.5
      exit 1
    fi

    echo $$GCLOUD_KEYSTORE_CONTENT | base64 --decode > $$HOME/.gradle/daemon/7.5/keystore.jks
    
    cd android
    chmod +x ./gradlew
    ./gradlew clean assembleRelease -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=$$HOME/.gradle/daemon/7.5/keystore.jks \
                               -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=$$GCLOUD_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD \
                               -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=$$GCLOUD_KEY_ALIAS \
                               -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=$$GCLOUD_KEY_PASSWORD

This project is for my employer, we're migrating from building using AppCenter to GCP. FYI I've renamed a few things to hide the employer identity, but it shouldn't affect anything.  My secrets are located in the Google Secrets manager, and my cloudbuild.yaml file also calls for these secrets. I'm not sure why the build process can't find the keystore file which is created in the build step.  Node version is 18.0.0 Gradle version 7.5 React native version 0.67.4  I am not sure what else to say, so if anyone can help and needs me to give more information feel free to ask. Thanks.  I've tried a ton of different approaches, manually setting the storeFile path to somewhere else, changing the way the secrets are called, etc.

Have you checked the logs? What do the logs show? Can you elaborate on your issue by sharing the steps you are following about your infrastructure to replicate the issue and the document you are following? Also have a look at this Documentation.

Thanks for that documentation, I found that this issue seemed unrelated to what I was asking about, there was a separate log that I found a fix for and this cleared up entirely. thanks.
